# KNative functions: Sclaed down to zero after 30s even if grace period is increased

Tags: knative, knative-serving, knative-functions

I configured my KNative serving like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: operator.knative.dev/v1beta1
kind: KnativeServing
metadata:
  name: knative-serving
  namespace: knative-serving
spec:
  ingress:
    kourier:
      enabled: true
  config:
    network:
      ingress-class: "kourier.ingress.networking.knative.dev"
    autoscaler:
      scale-to-zero-grace-period: "600s"
```

I have a function which takes longer than 30 seconds to become ready. I am fine with that. But its pod is still killed after 30 seconds. Is there anything else to check (i.e. some setting in `func.yaml`)?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set either [`timeoutSeconds`](https://knative.dev/docs/serving/configuration/config-defaults/#revision-timeout-seconds) or configure [`readinessProbe`s and `livenessProbe`s](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) which are longer than the Knative defaults.  You should be able to see the defaults in the applied service `spec`.